# Erro ao enviar informações ao mongodb no node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Olá pessoal estou com o seguinte problema, meu node está acusando o erro:

`ReferenceError: Cannot access 'user' before initialization`

Estou trabalhando com registro de usuario com Schema no caso abaixo mostro um *POST*:

```
app.post('/register', (req,res) =>{
    

    const {nomecompleto,email,password} = req.body
    const user = new user({nomecompleto,email,password}) 



})
```

estou importando o arquivo model user que ficou assim  `const User = Require('./model/user')`

Já tentei diversas ações para corrigir mais ele ainda continua dando erro na linha 36 no caso quando colocamos a *const*

Answer (score 0):

Conforme falou na pergunta, se você fez:

```
const User = require('./model/user')
```

Ao criar uma instância de user, deveria fazer:

```
const user = new User({nomecompleto,email,password})
```

Assim, provavelmente terá o resultado esperado.

A diferença do meu código para o seu é que estou instanciando um objeto `"User"`, o mesmo que eu fiz o import com o comando `require`.

Em seu código está usando com a letra <kbd>u</kbd> minúsculo.